Form in foreach in Razor view: Validation is shown to all the elements
Consider the following Razor code
foreach(Person p in Model.Persons){
    <form>

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => p.Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => p.Name)

        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => p.Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => p.Surname)

        <button type="submit">Save</button>
        
    </form>
}

In the processed .html each Person will have an identical name attribute with each other. This leads to a wrong behaviour when the validation does not succeed: each Person will have an error message even if I was editing only one of them.
What would be the best way to resolve this issue?
My Post handler is as follows
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SavePerson(Person person){
    // ...
}

and it'd be great to leave it as it is.

The reason why the validation error will show for all input textbox is  Html.TextBoxFor and Html.ValidationMessageFor helpers generate HTML elements with the same name attributes for each Person in the list. This results in validation messages being shown for all items when only one item is edited and validation fails.
To solve this issue, I suggest you could consider create a partial views to split each Person form and handle the submit individually.
More details, you could refer to below example:
1.Create a partial views inside the shared view folder:
@model Person

<form asp-action="SavePerson" method="post">
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.Id)

    <label for="Name">Name</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Name)

    <label for="Surname">Surname</label>
    @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Surname)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Surname)

    <button type="submit">Save</button>
</form>

2.Use it inside the view:
@foreach (var person in Model.Persons)
{
    @await Html.PartialAsync("_PersonForm", person)
}

Result:

Post method:


My whole test sample:
Person model:
public class Person
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
    [Required]

    public string Surname { get; set; }

}

Home controller:
    public IActionResult Index()
    {
        List<Person> people = new List<Person>() { new Person { Id=1, Name="test1", Surname="test1" }, new Person { Id = 2, Name = "test2", Surname = "test2" } };   

        return View(people);
    }
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult SavePerson(Person person)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // Save the person data to the database or perform necessary operations
           
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

       
        return View(person);   
    }

View:
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Home Page";
}

@model List<Person>


<div class="text-center">
    <h1 class="display-4">Welcome</h1>
    <p>Learn about <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/core">building Web apps with ASP.NET Core</a>.</p>
</div>

<><hr/>

    @foreach (var person in Model)
    {
        @await Html.PartialAsync("_PersonForm", person)
    }




    @section scripts {
    <partial name="_ValidationScriptsPartial" />
    }  

Test result:
It works at myside, each submit button works for each form.


This is very nice and clean, thank you! Did you write the SavePerson method in the primary View's controller? Because to me it does not work (same problem I described in the question), as they keep having the same names. Otherwise, could you be so kind, if you want, to upload the project somewhere so I could give it a look? Thank you again.

I write the method inside the homecontroller and the view is used inside the home controller index view, let me update my answer.

Using data model items index can solve this problem:
@model IList<Person>
<form asp-action="SavePerson" method="post">    
@for(int i=0; i < Model.Count(); i++)
{
    <div>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Name)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].Name)
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => Model[i].Surname)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => Model[i].Surname)
    </div>
    <br>
}
<button type="submit">Save</button> 
</form>

Passing all the list back to the controller can be useful to show error messages:
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult SavePerson(List<Person> model)        
{            
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        // Process data 
        return RedirectToAction(some_action);
    }
    // Show errors 
    return View("Index", model);
}

If move the <form> tag inside the for loop then only data for specific item will be send to the controlled side.
